# read user input into an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code which reads user input into an array list. how can I write the same code using an array list of strings instead of integer.

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter some numbers");

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        input.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Comment: Go on, try it, I am sure you can get at least half way there by yourself.

Comment: I have tried it, but no luck. I just didn't post it here with the question.

Comment: How can we fix your mistakes if we can not see them?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `ArrayList<Integer>` with `ArrayList<String>`. Then you can use `Scanner.hasNext()` to check for valid input and then scan it to a String with something like `String foo = Scanner.next()`. Note that `.next()` only reads input to the next whitespace, so if you want to read multiple words, `Scanner.hasNextLine()` and `Scanner.nextLine()` are the methods you want (As they read input to the next newline).

Answer (score -1):

Scanner class has `next();` and `nextLine();` methods that can be used to get data in the form of string.
 Using   `next();` method will block the code till it get the input. So `nextLine();` method can be used to get the complete String and that String can be splitted in to tokens using delimiter

```
 private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter some String :");
        String ip=scan.nextLine();         
        input.addAll(Arrays.asList(ip.split("\\s")));  

        System.out.println(input);
  }
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Enter some numbers");` - yep

Comment: Okay @Scary Wombat . I will optimise it